# How To Fire OnTextChangeListenerOn Edittext Available in ListViewAdapter as a Item in android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, listviewitem, listview-adapter

I have one ListView with edit text as a list item binding with ListViewAdapter. i want to put validation on EditText. like if user enter "85" in Edittext, it automatically set as a "0085". in-short if user enters less then 4 characters, it will automatically add 0 as a prefix and it will be set 4 characters. please help me..

Comment: check length  and if it is > 4 then append zero else do nothing. or take int string _str="00"; if its >4 then merge _str+entered text.

Comment: yes its right, but how can i implement addTextChanged Listener on listview item?

Answer (score 0):

i have Done this type of thing in one of my project. i have modified code acording to your answer and put it here. try it out.

Inside your AdapterFile(extends BaseAdapter)  you can Specify `addTextChanged Listener` like as Below

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder holder;
convertView = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.order_listview_detail_row, null);
    holder.txtpromised_quantity = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtpromised_quantity);
    holder.txtpromised_quantity.setTag(position);
}

holder.txtpromised_quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity.getTag()
                        .toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity.getTag()
                        .toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().length()==4) {
                    qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity
                            .getTag().toString());
                    holder.txtpromised_quantity.setText(holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().toString());
                } else if (holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().length()==3) {
                    qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity
                            .getTag().toString());
                    holder.txtpromised_quantity.setText("0"+holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().toString());
                }else if (holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().length()==2) {
                    qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity
                            .getTag().toString());
                    holder.txtpromised_quantity.setText("00"+holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().toString());
                }else if (holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().length()==1) {
                    qtypos = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtpromised_quantity
                            .getTag().toString());
                    holder.txtpromised_quantity.setText("000"+holder.txtpromised_quantity.getText().toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.